# How to show a message box in smalltalk? (squeak)

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

How do I show a message in a message box dialog with a single "OK" button in smalltalk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Squeak, you would write

```
 UIManager default inform: 'This is the standard way'.
```

Comment: This was fast :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

And you can even tell every object to do so using `self inform: 'Convenience method'`, as `#inform:` is defined on Object to do what aka.nice described.